# How to read from a pipe keeping positional parameters?

Tags: shell-script, pipe, arguments

I'm writing a small script that I'd like to make it working from a piped input or else from the command-line arguments.

```
my_function() {
  for i in "$@"; do
    echo "$i"
    echo -----
  done
}

if [ -t 0 ]; then
  my_function "$@"    # command-line arguments
else
  my_function $(cat)  # pipe
fi
```

These options work:

```
$ my_script 1 2 3 4
$ echo 1 2 3 4 | my_script
1
-----
2
-----
3
-----
4
-----
```

This also works fine:

```
$ my_script 1 "2 3" 4
1
-----
2 3
-----
4
-----
```

The problem comes when I'm trying to keep positional parameters from a pipe:

```
$ echo 1 "2 3" 4 | my_script
1
-----
2
-----
3
-----
4
-----
```

---

```
$ echo 1 "'2 3'" 4 | my_script
1
-----
'2
-----
3'
-----
4
-----
```

Instead of `my_function $(cat)`, I've tried to use `read` without good results, something like:

```
read input
my_function $input
```

Any ideas on this? I know word splitting is hard.

Comment: You quote `$@`, so why not quote `$(cat)`?

Comment: It still wouldn't work. The answer is "use `eval`", which means the answer is "rethink what you're doing".

Comment: I agree with @MichaelHomer however if the use case is narrow, `xargs` might do the trick - check out the output from `echo 1 '"2 3"' 4 | xargs -n 1`

Comment: Your first stdin example (`echo 1 "2 3" 4 | my_script`) can *not* be made to work. Your command just receives `1 2 3 4` on stdin; it has absolutely no way to know that `echo` was passed 3 arguments instead of 4. Only your last example stands a chance.

Comment: @iruvar Probably you should make that an answer. Especially if you include in that answer an explanation of why it's hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look in this technique with bash 4.4:

```
function myf { 
  if ! [ -t 0 ];then 
    declare -a args=\($(</dev/stdin)\);
    set -- "${args[@]}"; 
  fi;
  for i in "$@";do 
    echo "$i";
    echo -----;
  done 
}
```

Testing:

```
$ function myf { if ! [ -t 0 ];then declare -a args=\($(</dev/stdin)\);set -- "${args[@]}"; fi;for i in "$@";do echo "$i";echo -----;done }
$ myf 1 "2 3" 4
1
-----
2 3
-----
4
-----

$ echo $'1 "2 3" 4'|myf
1
-----
2 3
-----
4
-----
```

Same result can be achieved also with:

```
$ echo 1 \"2 3\" 4 |myf
$ echo 1 "'2 3'" 4 |myf
```

But `echo 1 "2 3" 4` is not going to work because double quotes are ignored by bash in this syntax:

```
$ echo 1 "2 3" 4
1 2 3 4
```